# QML anchors to ApplicationWindow via id not work

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I test a simple QML(Qt sdk version 5.3.2) program like this

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: appWin

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
```

I want the text will be layed on the bottom of application window, that's work. But if I change `anchors.bottom: parent.bottom` to `anchors.bottom: appWin.bottom` (via id), anchors not work anymore, is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ApplicationWindow` does not ultimately derive from `Item`, so it does not have an `anchors` property that's why using the window's `id` does not work.  So why does using `parent`?  Because the children *you* define in an `ApplicationWindow` become [children of an intermediate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#data-prop) `Item` called `contentItem`:

> If you assign an Item to the data list, it becomes a child of the
>   Window's contentItem, so that it appears inside the window. The item's
>   parent will be the window's contentItem, which is the root of the Item
>   ownership tree within that Window. ... It should not generally be
>   necessary to refer to the data property, as it is the default property
>   for Window and thus all child items are automatically assigned to this
>   property.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a bug, but it can be by design according following [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#restrictions):

> For performance reasons, you can only anchor an item to its siblings
>   and direct parent

It's not really clear how we can specify `direct parent` when anchoring. QML translator may only accept `parent` to reference parent qml item.

Comment: It is not a bug, and you can specify the direct parent by it's `id` or by using `parent`.